# Caching and reusing controls at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, caching

I am developing an application which among its functions, allows users to enter new objects into the system (for example, a product). When creating a new product, the user can choose a category, and then the program proceeds to load any number of custom attributes for that category that the user set up previously.

The program loads and displays the attributes without a problem. However, the issue is that there could be hundreds of different categories, all with their own set of attributes. Because of this, I don't want to query the database and set up the controls each time the user switches to a different product category.

I am wrestling with what would be the best method to "cache" a category's attributes and controls in memory once loaded so that subsequent loads are instant.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, my question is regarding caching the **controls**, not the **attributes (data)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I came to a conclusion that it's best to create a UserControl container and populate each one with the needed attributes and their controls, and then cache that UserControl in a Dictionary. After testing, I noticed that this is extremely efficient and also **fast**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as caching goes, you may want to check the Caching appliction block from Patterns & Practices [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), you can use this block to cache the data from the DB as long as you know they don't change that much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem isn't the data from the database - that is easy to cache. It's the controls that are created from the data that are the problem.